# Why is the SelectedItem property of my DataGrid subclass set to Nothing?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have subclassed the WPF DataGrid in my VB.NET application because I will need to use this component frequently but also need to have some extra features, in this case adding a new row when the tab key is pressed on the bottom right cell.

I have Overidden the OnKeyDown event of the base class. This is being triggered when the tab keys is pressed while the grid is focused, exactly as I want. However, when the event is triggered I need to be able to determine whether I'm on the bottom-right cell or not. To do this I'd like to get the SelectedItem property of my DataGrid and use that to determine which cell is selected.

I am doing all of this programmatically because I don't want users to have to write any more XAML than they would have to for a regular datagrid. It should function in exactly the same way except if you tab on the bottom right cell a new row is added and the first cell of that row is selected. this should apply no matter how many rows/columns the user has in the datagrid.

The code below shows what I want to do but the SelectedItem is not set.

```vb
    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
        If e.Key = Key.Tab Then

            Dim colIndex As Integer = Me.Columns.IndexOf(Me.CurrentColumn)
            Dim colCount As Integer = Me.Columns.Count - 1

            If -1 = colIndex Then
                'the next line throws a System.NullReferenceException because SelectedItem is not set
                If SelectedItem.Equals(Items(Items.Count - 1)) Then
                    Focus()
                    Dim dgrCI = New DataGridCellInfo(Items(Items.Count - 1), Columns(colIndex))
                    ScrollIntoView(Items(Items.Count - 1))
                    BeginEdit()

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The SelectedItem property should be set to the last item in the table but is instead set to Nothing. Why is this?

Edit:
The answer from Ppp is correct. it seems that by the time the OnKeydown event is triggered the DataGrid has already lost focus. I resolved this issue by using the OnPreviewKeydown event instead.

Comment: How did the index of the current column get to -1?

Comment: I checked the value of the colIndex variable in debug mode when the I tabbed on the bottom right cell. The value is -1. That part seems to be working fine. it is just the SelectedItem variable that's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your tab key is pressed in the last cell you basically tab out of the datagrid which is why I am guessing your SelectedItem is null.